# How to reference background image via DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I know I'm doing something wrong here:

```
document.getElementById("body_bg_top").style.background-image:url(main_bg_top.jpg);
```

If anyone can correct me I would appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: If you change the style via DOM, remove the hyphens from the style names and write the first character after a hyphen with capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background-image has no hyphen, so just

```
document.getElementById("body_bg_top").style.backgroundImage="url(main_bg_top.jpg)";
```

Also need to replace the colon with an equals and wrap the url() in quotes.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use:

```
$('#element-name').css('background-image');
```

to access that particular CSS property.

Comment: Why use jQuery for a simple task?

Comment: I'm just providing another method of doing this. I guess it wouldn't be necessary for this specific example to use jQuery, but it might be easier if you're trying to do a lot of these type of selectors/manipulations.